# Samba fails to connect to VMWare CentOS guest from Mac Mavericks host

Tags: macos, centos, vmware-fusion, smb

Trying to connect through smb to my VMWare guest at 192.168.0.138:139 gives me the following message:

> **There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.0.138"**
>
> This file server will not allow any additional users to log on. Try to connect again later.

I can ping and SSH to it fine, having some problems accessing it through http (though whether it's related, I'm not sure)

I'm using Bridged Networking (Automatic) and my /etc/samba/smb.conf is as follows:

```
[global]
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level = 3
smb ports = 139

[rails]
comment = Rails Websites
path = /websites/mysite/rails
valid users = @rails
force group = rails
create mask = 777
directory mask = 777
public = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
```

We definitely had it working on another Mavericks machine, but that one is now dead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your iptables file to allow connections on ports used by smb.

Open /etc/sysconfig/iptables and add these lines:

```
# accept connections on smb ports
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
```

Refer to this for more information

[CentOS Samba Setup](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba)

Comment: That was it! I also added one for port 80 and now I'm all set for browsing as well.